# Rider unable to restore dotnet core packages on mac

Tags: .net-core, jetbrains-ide, rider

I get the following error when I try to restore a dotnetcore project on my mac in Rider.
The sad thing is this error only comes in Jetbrains Rider. I can run my project from the command line and Visual Studio. Any ideas?
`[NU1202] Package Serilog.Extensions.Hosting 4.0.0-dev-00051 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Serilog.Extensions.Hosting 4.0.0-dev-00051 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)`

Comment: In case you run the `dotnet restore` command via the terminal for the project folder, will it restore all packages without this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running an older version of Rider. After upgrading to the newest version, it worked fine.